# issue with screen swipe detection code

Tags: android

Can someone help me with the code below. I am using this code to detect finger swipe on the screen.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class ActivitySwipeDetector implements View.OnTouchListener {  

 private Activity activity;
 static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
 private float downX, downY, upX, upY;

 public ActivitySwipeDetector(final Activity activity) { 
  this.activity = activity;
 }

 public void onRightToLeftSwipe() {
}

 public void onLeftToRightSwipe(){
}

 public void onTopToBottomSwipe(){
}

 public void onBottomToTopSwipe(){
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
 switch(event.getAction()){
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
Log.i("msg", "in MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN "+event.getX());
downX = event.getX();
downY = event.getY();
 }
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
Log.i("msg", "in MotionEvent.ACTION_UP "+event.getX());
upX = event.getX();
upY = event.getY();

 float deltaX = downX - upX;
 float deltaY = downY - upY;

 // swipe horizontal?
   if(Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE){
  // left or right
  if(deltaX < 0) { this.onLeftToRightSwipe(); return true; }
  if(deltaX > 0) { this.onRightToLeftSwipe(); return true; }
 } else { Log.i("msg", "X-axis Swipe was only " + downX+"-"+upX + " long, need at least " +     
  MIN_DISTANCE); }

 // swipe vertical?
 if(Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE){
  // top or down
  if(deltaY < 0) { this.onTopToBottomSwipe(); return true; }
  if(deltaY > 0) { this.onBottomToTopSwipe(); return true; }
 } else { Log.i("msg", "Y-axis Swipe was only " + downY+"-"+upY  + " long, need at least " + 
MIN_DISTANCE); }

 //     return true;
}
}
return false;
 }

 }
```

and this is how I am using this class in my code

```
  myTextView.setOnTouchListener(new ActivitySwipeDetector(this) {
        public void onRightToLeftSwipe() {
            //do some stuff;
        }
        public void onLeftToRightSwipe() {
            //do some stuff;
        }
        public void onTopToBottomSwipe() {
            //do some stuff;
        }
        public void onBottomToTopSwipe() {
            //do some stuff;
        }
    });
```

When I test this code(directly on phone, not on emulator) both the upX ad downX variables are returning same values. Same is the case with upY and downY values. And hence method onLeftToRightSwipe() etc are not being invoked in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a line "return true;" in case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your switch statement, you need to put a `break;` at the end of each case.

```
switch(event.getAction()){

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        Log.i("msg", "in MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN "+event.getX());
        downX = event.getX();
        downY = event.getY();
        break;
        }
    case...
```

Comment: but then it is exiting the MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN after touch. hence the execution does not go to the case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP. It has to capture starting position in downX and closing spotition in upX. By putting the break only downX gets polupated.